# How do I find out the duration of each task within a Hudson job?

Tags: java, ant, build, hudson

I'm interested in finding out how long each step within a job is taking.
Example: one of my jobs performs csv checkout, run ant build, publish javadocs, archives artifacts, run unit tests, etc. Is there a way to find out how long each took?

I've already added timestamps to the build.xml being used, but now I need to find out the duration (or timestamp) of the other job tasks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the console output (it's an item in the project menu in the Hudson UI)

Comment: Yes, I even looked at the raw output, but that's just whatever my build.xml produces. I'm unable to find any timestamp for any of the Post-Build Actions for a job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** after comment :

Try [PostbuildPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin), see usage examples [here](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-Start-time-End-time-Duration-of-a-job-td4580312.html).

You may start your ant scripts with [ProfileLogger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html#ProfileLogger), available with Ant >= 1.8.x :
`ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.ProfileLogger ...`

The output looks like that (taken from ant manual) :

```
Buildfile: ...\build.xml

Target aTarget: started Thu Jan 22 09:01:00 CET 2009

echo: started Thu Jan 22 09:01:00 CET 2009
     [echo] echo-task

echo: finished Thu Jan 22 09:01:00 CET 2009 (250ms)

zip: started Thu Jan 22 09:01:00 CET 2009
      [zip] Building zip: ...\my.zip

zip: finished Thu Jan 22 09:01:01 CET 2009 (1313ms)

Target aTarget: finished Thu Jan 22 09:01:01 CET 2009 (1719ms)

Target anotherTarget: started Thu Jan 22 09:01:01 CET 2009

echo: started Thu Jan 22 09:01:01 CET 2009
     [echo] another-echo-task

echo: finished Thu Jan 22 09:01:01 CET 2009 (0ms)

Target anotherTarget: finished Thu Jan 22 09:01:01 CET 2009 (0ms)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 2 seconds
```

Other options :
[Antcontrib PerformanceListener](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/performance_monitor.html)
[Antstatistics Logger](http://code.google.com/p/antstatistics/)

Comment: I have something like that that works in my build.xml today, but I was curious if there was something for the entire Hudson job? When I click on job->Configure there are several options (checkboxes) of tasks that it can perform (e.g. archiving). These are outside of my build.xml and that's why I wanted to know if Hudson provides a way to timestamp each one of those events?

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to give this a try

Comment: When using Jenkins/Hudson with the Ant profile logger, add the `-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.ProfileLogger` to the `target` field of the Ant configuration. I tried some other places in vain.